# Deleting nodes in linked list when strings match

Tags: c

Hello I am working on a linked list - struct based project and I am asking you guys for little help. 
I have to delete a node from my linked list when one string is part of a string from struct data.

So far i have come up with this. I was able to use `strstr()` to find match in two strings, but after it displays that string #1 is in string #2 the whole program falls.

```
void zmaz(STUFF *p_akt, STUFF *p_prv, STUFF *p_vymaz){
char meno_autor[100];
scanf("%s", meno_autor);
while(p_akt!=NULL) {
    if(strstr(p_akt->autori,meno_autor)!=NULL){
       printf("string %s is in %s\n", meno_autor, p_akt->autori);

       p_vymaz=p_akt;
        if (p_prv == p_vymaz){ //deleting the first node
            p_prv = p_prv->p_dalsi;
        }

        else {
            p_akt = p_prv;
            while (p_akt->p_dalsi != p_vymaz) p_akt = p_akt->p_dalsi;
            p_akt->p_dalsi = p_vymaz->p_dalsi;
        }
        free((void*)p_vymaz);
    }
p_akt=p_akt->p_dalsi;
}
}
```

I dont have to only delete a node, but also move next nodes so there is no gap between any of them.
I tried to explain everything as much as I could. Thank you!

Comment: try using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it fails is because you make the following sequence of code:

```
while(){
    if(){
       ...
       p_vymaz=p_akt;
       ...
       free((void*)p_vymaz);
    }
    p_akt=p_akt->p_dalsi;
}
```

You have freed p_akt by assigning p_vymaz to p_akt and then freeing p_vymaz. As such, `p_akt->p_dalsi` is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

I really hope this is not a real project. You have a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) hanging there, waiting to happen.

Since this is a homework, I'd tell you to use a debugger, like @Mitch Wheat suggested. But also keep in mind that if you write code in your mother tangue, which is not english, it will be very hard for The People From The Internet to follow it and help.

Luckily some will, like @Marc Claesen here.